# Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' that is compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.274780

Tags: xamarin.forms

**I have this error:**

> Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages.
>   One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the existing packages.config file. All dependency constraints must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current package operation: 'Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.121934 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.121934 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.121934 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.121934 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.121934 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0)'
>   Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' that is compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.274780 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)'.**

while am trying to update NuGet packages. I tried to find a solution but no solution is working with me.

am using visual studio community for mac.

So please help because am new to Xamarine.

Comment: I am also having a big problem with Xamarin.Android.Support.Design. My scenario is different. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50426755/xamarin-android-support-design-causes-crash-on-launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API level 23 is Android 6. Open the properties of your Android app and under Application set the Target Framework to at least Android 6.0.

[image]

I always use the latest version, so 27 (Oreo 8.1). Under Android Manifest you can still set the Minimum Android version to API Level 23.

Comment: I did that, but unfortunately it doesn't work and i got the same problem

Comment: @AliAl-sinan post pictures of your project settings. Open Android SDK manager and make sure you have the Oreo tools installed.

Comment: That's work successfuly, I only update install (Oreo 8.1) in the SDK manager, change target framework to 8.1 and Target Android version to 8.1. After that everything works fine !! ... Thank you so much bro

Answer (score 0):

I think you should really update your Android.Support Libraries to version 26.1.0.1.
Sometimes you can have some troubles doing it inside Visual Studio so do this:

Close your solution and edit your android csproj file:

Be sure to have these package references with the corresponding version:

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.5.0.280555" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="26.1.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="26.1.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="26.1.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" Version="26.1.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" Version="26.1.0.1" />
```

Save the file and open again your solution, Visual Studio will update your Android project with the correct Xamarin.Forms version and the correct Android.Support libraries.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: I also tried that but still doesn't work and I got the same problems