# Xamarin.Android.Support.Design causes crash on launch

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Start with a fresh Android project in Visual Studio Professional 15.6.6, on Windows.
Install Xamarin.Android.Support.Design from NuGet.
Try to run on an Android 8 phone (mine is a BLU Vivo XL3).
It probably won't run. It may (or may not) complain as follows:

```
 "Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha9.png from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f020000
```

I also tried it on Visual Studio Professional 15.7.1. Same problem.

Any work arounds?

Related question here:

[Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' that is compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.274780](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250703/unable-to-find-a-version-of-xamarin-android-support-design-that-is-compatible)

Comment: does the app run in Oreo Emulator?

Comment: Yes, on both Android 8.0 and 8.1.

Comment: [according to this topic](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104135/notfoundexception-file-res-drawable-xxhdpi-v4-abc-ab-share-pack-mtrl-alpha9-png), select "Use Fast Deployment (Debug mode only)" in android project properties

Comment: Tried that; no luck.

Comment: post some pictures of your project configuration or the csproj file in a code formatting. maybe this helps. Do you have a different phone to test?